# What kind of encoding is this? _0x5d78a7

Tags: javascript, encoding

how are you?

I've been trying for hours to understand what code this is to decode, I don't know what kind of encoding this was, I've tried everything... Hex, Base64, etc... Help me, please! The code is below:

```
function _0x415c() {
    var _0x5d78a7 = ["76780CLVYuB", "575860TjCrgq", "278991YQCHtU", "543592jjcALm", "12lhjAtx", "2sdRamg", "726184NnOvGS", "45zKJbOx", "ById", "77TyiDmE", "1031964iRWxPe", "getElement", "textConten", "660947xlKNBZ", "log"];
    _0x415c = function () {
        return _0x5d78a7;
    };
    return _0x415c();
}
```

What's this???

```
"76780CLVYuB", "575860TjCrgq", "278991YQCHtU", "543592jjcALm", "12lhjAtx", "2sdRamg", "726184NnOvGS", "45zKJbOx", "ById", "77TyiDmE", "1031964iRWxPe", "getElement", "textConten", "660947xlKNBZ", "log"
```

and

```
_0x415c
_0x5d78a7
_0x415c
```

These codes are inside a .js file!

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem an encoding, but either an obfuscation of code, or a de-compilation  attempt (so maybe they are pointer values in assembler.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an encoding. E.g. the function is simply named `_0x415c`.

The source code is by all certainty run through an obfuscator (most probably this https://obfuscator.io/) to make it harder for you to read the source code. Unfortunately not anything you can do about it.

Typically, if you want to find out what's happening, you can step through the code in a debugger.